# Potential pitfalls with own DateTime helper class in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

In my application I use DateTime class instead of (prefered?) DateTimeOffset to handle time. I just got used to it and it is much easier for me to do so.
I do something like this:

```
public static class TimeHelper
{
    public static TimeSpan Offset { get; private set; }
    static TimeHelper()
    {
        offset = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
    }

    public static DateTime Now
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.UtcNow + offset;
        }
    }
}
```

It is easy for me to manipulate in this way because whenever I write a date to a file I simply use Ticks and I am able to convert it back to any timezone. Should I really start using DateTimeOffset now?

Comment: Yes you should. DateTimeOffset was created to handle the very scenarios you mention. The latest Hanselminutes [episode](http://hanselminutes.com/485/the-problem-with-datetime-nodatime-with-matt-johnson) explains why, and why your helper will get you into trouble - TimeZone is obsolete, your code has no idea whether DateTime is UTC or not so  you'll get errors each time there is a daylight saving change. Comparing datetimes on these dates will fail because your offsets will change but you'll have absolutely no idea this happened. Etc